# Find the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$, where $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=(2+x_n)^{1/2}$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

I have been given this hint in the problem: In order to determine the limit, it may be helpful to use the fact that if $y_n \rightarrow y$ and $y_n > 0$ for every $n$,then $\sqrt{y_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{y}$. You can use this without proving it. You can also use without proof the fact that if $0\le a \le b,$ then $\sqrt{a} \le \sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

To be sure the sequence is well-defined, Prove by induction that

$$(\forall n\ge 1)\;\;  x_n\ge 0$$

then use

$$|x_{n+1}-2|=\frac{|x_n-2|}{\sqrt{2+x_n}+2}$$
$$\le \frac 12|x_n-2|$$
$$\le \frac{1}{2^n}|x_1-2|$$

Comment: how did you get that $|x_{n+1}-2|=\frac{|x_n-2|}{\sqrt{2+x_n}+2}$?

Comment: @Housefire Multiply by the conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

You have: $|x_n - x_{n-1}| = \left|\sqrt{x_{n-1}+2}-\sqrt{x_{n-2}+2}\right|=\dfrac{|x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}|}{\sqrt{x_{n-1}+2}+\sqrt{x_{n-2}+2}}\le \dfrac{|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|}{2\sqrt{2}}$. This shows it's a Cauchy sequence, hence converges to $L$ that also satisfies: $L = \sqrt{L+2} \implies L = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt :

In the first, is easy to showing $x_n$ is incremental, just pose $f(x) =\sqrt{2+x}$ and use recurrence for showing $x_n<x_{n+1}$

And  you can see that $x_2=x_3=x_4=.......=2$

So $x_n\leq 2$ and for showing that also you can use recurrence

For $n=1$ $x_1\leq2$$\Rightarrow $$1\leq 2$ that is correct

Suppose $x_n\leq 2$

Let's show $x_{n+1}\leq 2$

We know $x_n\leq 2$

So $f(x_n) \leq f(2)$

so $x_{n+1}\leq 2$ because f is incremental

we see $x_n\leq 2$ and $x_n$ is incremental so $x_n $ is convergent and $\lim x_n=l$

So. $l=\sqrt{2+l} $$\Rightarrow $$ l^2-l-2=0$$\Rightarrow l=2$ or $l=-1 $but this is impossible because $l\geq 0$

So finally

$\lim x_n=2. $